# UIPickerView not connecting to the DataSource

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uipickerview

So my UIPickerView does not get connected to the DataSource. I Have no idea WHY.

I create a file with `UIPickerViewDelegate` and `UIPickerViewDataSource`, and properly do the procedure for bringing a UIPickerView on tapping a textField.

The pickerView works , but does not show any component. I have implemented

```
-(NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
{
return 3;
}

- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component 



- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component { 


- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component { 


- (CGFloat)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView widthForComponent:(NSInteger)component{
```

Any idea why the pickerView is not getting connected to the DataSource ?    I also tried NSLogging inside all these methods. `// Does not print`

I had also set

```
packSizePopPickerView.delegate = self;
packSizePopPickerView.dataSource = self;
packSizePopPickerView = [[UIPickerView alloc] init];
```

Comment: Do you set the `delegate` and `dataSource` properties of your `UIPickerView`?

Comment: What method are you setting the delegate and datasource in? Is the picker view created in IB or code? And don't create new posts - edit your posts if you need to add more information.

Comment: I set it up  in the cellForRowAtIndexPath, as I need it to appear for a textField, which is inside a UITableViewCell.... The thing is.. I have another view, which implements the SAME pickerView, and it works. WHY IS THIS not working !! ? :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In cellForRowAtIndexPath, you're setting packSizePopPickerView's dataSource/delegate, and THEN allocating/initializing packSizePopPickerView to a new UIPickerView. The NEW UIPickerView no longer has its delegate/dataSource set.

This is WRONG:

```
packSizePopPickerView.delegate = self;
packSizePopPickerView.dataSource = self;
packSizePopPickerView = [[UIPickerView alloc] init];
```

Try this:

```
packSizePopPickerView = [[UIPickerView alloc] init];
packSizePopPickerView.delegate = self;
packSizePopPickerView.dataSource = self;
```

Comment: I just tried it, still does not show 3 components. And I dont think your answer is right, as it does not matter where you assign this.

Comment: You still have not answered my question - are you setting this pickerview up in IB or in code? Try reloading your pickerview via [myPickerView reloadAllComponents] in cellForRowAtIndexPath, and see if your delegate/datasource methods are called.

Comment: @Thomashw : I do it code. I do not use the InterfaceBuilder. I tried reloading. *Still no progress*

Comment: @Legolas Please show in what method you're adding the pickerview to your view, and how you're doing so. Show all of your code in context. Showing it out of context and not where it's actually located with respect to the rest of your code doesn't help.

Comment: I use the exact same code for another view; and it worked. I have no idea why this one is troubling me. And FYI packSizePopPickerView is the pickerview with 3 components that I am trying to use.

Comment: @Legolas Update your first post with information about the problem, like the code you just linked to. I've updated my post above. Try it out.

Comment: @Legolas No problem. If you can update your post with the code you posted on pastie it'd make this question a lot more relevant for people in the future.

Answer (score 0):

You need to explicitly tell the picker what its data sources and delegates are.

myPicker.delegate = someController;
myPicker.datasource = someController;